# Need to pass argument from sys.argv[1] as input to glob() in python

Tags: python, windows

I have a situation where i need to take argument from command-line and use that string (expression) I need to print files based on that regex.
I want to use `glob` to parse my string as i can pass regex to filter.
excerpt from python file:

```
dated = sys.argv[1]
files = glob.glob(dated)
```

This throws me empty list

```
> python analysis.py <some_expression>
[]
```

However, if I give any value manually:

```
dated = '*.xlsx' # example sake
files = glob.glob(dated)
print(files)
```

it prints:

```
[<list of files conforming to the required filter>]
```

It's obvious that the CLI arguments that it prints above, but I want the CLI argument to work properly.

I tested manually if the arguments are actually testing and it worked, so the `sys.argv[1]` is working but the results are not getting parsed in the `glob.glob()`

any ideas if I am missing something somewhere?

Comment: Are you working on Linux?

Comment: no, its on Windows.

Comment: I am not sure but I have only suggestions. 1. Try to escape the star. 2. Try quotes. If none of them works, please print the sys.argv[1]. Maybe I missed something. Could you please give me the result of ```print(sys.argv[1]) ``` ?

Comment: Thanks Erdogan for trying, like I mentioned, ```sys.argv[1]``` prints fine. i get the result, but this is not getting parsed within `glob()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue her is not in Python, but in the shell that invokes it. Most shells I know (definitely all Linux shells) perform glob expansion before passing arguments to the executable they spawn (your Python script, in this case). This means that, at most, `sys.argv[1]` would contain the first file matching the glob expression you pass, and anyway, applying `glob` on it would not do any good.

For example, if your work directory has files `a.xlsx`, `b.xlsx` and `c.xlsx`, and you invoke you code using:

```
python mycode.py *.xlsx
```

Then the shell will actually `glob` the argument you specified, and will pass the results to your script, making the following true:

```
sys.argv[1:] == [`a.xlsx`, `b.xlsx`, `c.xlsx`]
```

In fact, instead of explicitly invoking `glob`, you can simply iterate on `sys.argv[1:]`.